# HTC Wildfire Plugin for debugging not working in UBUNTU

Tags: android, debugging, htc-android

I got this following devices :

1. I got my Ubuntu 64 bits PC
2. I got my Wildfire (not S, but normal Wildfire)

In my phone,
I have turned on:

1. USB debugging mode
2. Also in the charging mode

However, ECLIPSE didn't find my device in their DEVICE section. So, I am wondering for the ideas ! :)

Thank you !

Comment: Have you installed USB Driver?

Comment: @PareshMayani I have worked with my Samsung devices (Galaxy Tab, Galaxy Captivate) on various Linux installations (Ubuntu 10.4 and up, Fedora Core 15,16) without the need to install additional drivers. My assumption is that you don't need drivers to work with ADB on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you done this setting? (Step 4 mentioned at [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html))

If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a **udev** rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, see [**USB Vendor IDs**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#VendorIds), below.

To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:
Log in as root and create this file: **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**.
Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.
Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to writing udev rules.

Now execute:

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```